# Need to increase code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I have 61% coverage i need to increase saveAccount() method.

```
public with sharing class AccountCustomLookupCntrl {
      public Account account {get;set;} // new account to create
      public List<Account> results{get;set;} // search results
      public string searchString{get;set;} // search keyword
      public boolean isStudent{get;set;}
      public boolean showNewAcc{get;set;}
      public boolean isPersonAccounts{get;set;}
      public String fName{get;set;}
      public String lName{get;set;}
      public String homePhone{get;set;}
      string recTypeId;
      string refType;
      public AccountCustomLookupCntrl() {
            account = new Account();
            isPersonAccounts = true;
            showNewAcc = true;
            // get the current search string
            searchString = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('lksrch');
            String isStuStr = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('isStudent');
            refType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('refType');
            if(searchString != null && searchString != ''){
                searchString = searchString.trim();
            }
            if(refType != null && refType != '' && refType.equalsIgnoreCase('Agent')){
                recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();
                isPersonAccounts = false;
                showNewAcc = false;
            }else if(refType != null && refType != '' && refType.equalsIgnoreCase('Teaching Staff')){
                recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Teacher').getRecordTypeId();
                showNewAcc = false;
            }else if(isStuStr != null && isStuStr == 'false'){
                isStudent = false;
                recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Parent').getRecordTypeId();
            }else{
                isStudent = true;
                recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Student').getRecordTypeId();
            }
            account.RecordTypeId = recTypeId; 
            system.debug('account: '+account);
            runSearch();  
      }

      // performs the keyword search
      public PageReference search() {
            runSearch();
            return null;
      }

      // prepare the query and issue the search command
      private void runSearch() {
            // TODO prepare query string for complex serarches & prevent injections
            results = performSearch(searchString);    
            system.debug('results=== '+results);           
      } 

      // run the search and return the records found. 
      private List<Account> performSearch(string searchString) {
        try{
            String soql;
            if(!isPersonAccounts){
                soql = 'select id, name,Type,RecordType.Name,isPersonAccount from account where RecordTypeId = \''+recTypeId+'\'';
                if(searchString != '' && searchString != null)
                  soql = soql +  ' and name LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';

            }else{
                soql = 'select id, firstname,lastname,RecordType.Name,PersonHomePhone,PersonEmail,Gender__pc,isPersonAccount,Address__c from account where RecordTypeId = \''+recTypeId+'\'';
                if(searchString != '' && searchString != null){
                  List<String> strList = searchString.split(' ');
                  if(strList != null)
                    searchString = strList.get(0);
                  soql = soql +  ' and (firstname LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';
                  soql = soql +  ' or lastname LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\')';
                }
            }


            soql = soql + ' limit 25';
            System.debug(soql);
            List<Account> resultsAcc = new List<Account>();
            resultsAcc = database.query(soql);
            system.debug('resultsAcc=== '+resultsAcc);
            system.debug('isPersonAccounts=== '+isPersonAccounts);
            if(isPersonAccounts && (resultsAcc == null || resultsAcc.size()==0)){
                recTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();
                soql = 'select id, name,Type,RecordType.Name,isPersonAccount from account where RecordTypeId = \''+recTypeId+'\'';
                if(searchString != '' && searchString != null)
                  soql = soql +  ' and name LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';

                resultsAcc = database.query(soql);
                isPersonAccounts = false;
            }
            system.debug('resultsAcc=== '+resultsAcc);
            return resultsAcc; 
        }catch(exception e){
            system.debug('exception: '+e.getMessage());
        }
        return new List<Account>();
      }

      // save the new account record
      public PageReference saveAccount() {
            if(fName != null && fName != ''){
                if(lName != null && lName !=''){
                    account.FirstName = fName;
                    account.LastName = lName;
                    if(account.Date_of_Birth__c != null)
                        account.PersonBirthdate = account.Date_of_Birth__c;
                    if(homePhone != null && homePhone != '')
                        account.PersonHomePhone = homePhone;

                    insert account;
                    // reset the account
                    account = new Account();
                    fName='';
                    lName='';
                    homePhone='';
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm,'New account record created.'));
                }else{
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Last Name : value is required'));
                }
            }else{
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'First Name : value is required'));
            }

            return null;
      }

      // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element
      public string getFormTag() {
            return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
      }

      // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element for the text box
      public string getTextBox() {
            return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
      }
}
```

Here my test class.

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountCustomLookupCntrl{
    static testMethod void accounttest() {

     Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMap1 = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rtA =  rtMap1.get('Parent').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtB =  rtMap1.get('Student').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtc =  rtMap1.get('Teacher').getRecordTypeId();
        Id rtD =  rtMap1.get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();

        account accB = new account();
        accB.LastName= 'test';
        accB.Date_of_Birth__c = system.today();
        //accB.recordtypeid = rtA;
        insert accB;

         account acc=new account();
        //acc.name='testhagas';
        acc.FirstName ='test';
        acc.LastName = 'last';
        acc.Email__c='tmc@gmail.com';
        acc.Phone='1201525252';
        acc.Date_of_Birth__c = system.today();
        acc.PersonBirthdate = acc.Date_of_Birth__c ;
        acc.PersonHomePhone = '1234567890';
        acc.Parent_Name__c = accB.id;
        //acc.recordtypeid =rtB;
        //acc.recordtypeid =rtc;

        insert acc;

        account acc1=new account();
        //acc.name='testhagas';
        acc1.name ='test';
        acc1.Email__c='tmc@gmail.com';
        acc1.Phone='1201525252';
        acc1.Date_of_Birth__c = system.today();
        //acc1.PersonBirthdate = acc1.Date_of_Birth__c ;
        //acc1.PersonHomePhone = '1234567890';
        acc1.Parent_Name__c = accB.id;
        acc1.recordtypeid =rtD;
        //acc.recordtypeid =rtc;

        insert acc1;


        AccountCustomLookupCntrl controller=new AccountCustomLookupCntrl();
        controller.saveAccount(); 
        controller.search();
        //controller.runSearch();
        controller.getFormTag();
        controller.getTextBox();

        }
}
```

Comment: try to save account with empty fname or lname, do a search for bunch of strings, for existing and non existing account, try Test.setCurrentPageReference to set url with some parameters, that define something in constructor

Comment: Please highlight the lines which are not covered.

Comment: welcome to SFSE! This is not a *please do my work for me* site. Here we help each other with the *specific* problems. Your question is likely to be closed because of the lack of effort you put into the question itself. Please consider asking a more specified question and highlight the lines that need to be covered.

Answer (score 2):

Your code requires that these properties not be null:

```
public String fName{get;set;}
public String lName{get;set;}
```

So in your tests, set those values and you will have coverage. Also, when writing your tests, break up the methods into functional units. Look at your code and see what it requires. While you are doing this ensure that was you are seeing in the code matching business requirements as sometimes when you review it when writing test you find errors in logic.

And after tests are written, if they begin to fail (if the are properly written) always think long and hard before modifying the test method. If they fail, it is likely some code change caused it. If the process should still be the same don't just change the test to pass, find out why it failed. Sorry rambling.....

I am obligated to point out that your test is not actually testing anything it is just running the engine so to speak.

Something like this:

```
public static testmethod void basicTest(){

  AccountCustomLookupCntrl controller=new AccountCustomLookupCntrl();
  controller.fName = 'First';
  controller.lName = 'Last';
  //set other required values
  controller.saveAccount();
  //Query for the resultant account and values
  Account[] a = [Select FirstName, LastName From Account]; 
  //assert that an account was created
  system.assertNotEquals(true,a.isEmpty(),'No Accounts Found');
  //assert that expected values were set
  system.assertEquals('First',a[0].FirstName);
  system.assertEquals('Last',a[0].LastName);

}
```

Comment: +1 for *if the are properly written*. Also, there is a single quote missing in your error message in the first assert. I'd edit it myself, but SE required edits to be at least 6 characters

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you some tips for writing test classes:

- Use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` methods
- It might be useful to move the setup part into [another method](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses)
- Make sure to test **EVERY POSSIBLE SCENARIO!** You can and should NOT test everything in one test method(or even worse: get coverage only)

And, probably the most important: **USE ASSERTS WHEN WRITING TEST CLASSES!!!**
Test classes are called **test** classes because they should actually *test* something and not only provide coverage, otherwise we would call them *coverage classes*. A test class without assert is useless, doesn't test anything and should not even be called a test class.

If, after this, some part of your code is still not covered ask yourself *"Do I even need this code? When is it used?"* and remove it.